# Installing pip: python-pip? or from python-setuptools

Tags: python, linux, pip, setuptools

I first use python in windows and now moved to Ubuntu. What's the difference between these two ways of installing pip?

I tried to install python-pip but was surprised to see the 30mb size while installing python-setuptools and then easy_install pip takes just few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` is a *different* project from `setuptools`. Installing just `python-setuptools` will not install `pip`.

Both install packages from the Python Package Index, but `pip` uses `setuptools` to provide a nicer interface and a slightly different approach. In other words, to use `pip` you first need to install `setuptools`.

`pip` offers more features than `setuptools`, including uninstalling and 'editable' installations where a git, subversion or mercurial repository is cloned and installed as a development egg.

Note that the `python-pip` package is **smaller** than the `python-setuptools` package:

- [`python-setuptools`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python-setuptools): size 444.7kb
- [`python-pip`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python-pip): size 101.2kb

You must be installing the `ca-certificates` or `build-essential` recommended packages to bring the installed size to 30MB.

Comment: I know what pip is and how to install it via easy_install. What I'm curios about is the other python-pip package in ubuntu which is about 30mb in size and how it differs in pip installed with easy_install

Comment: As formulated, your question seems to ask why you can install either `python-setuptools` or `python-pip` to install `pip`, suggesting that you thought the two were the same.

Comment: And according to the [package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python-pip) `python-pip` is merely 101 kb small, while [`python-setuptools`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python-setuptools) is 445kb, more than 4 times the size.

Comment: In my pc, installing python-pip comes with other packages and reaches 30.1mb in size. Like these  debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-4.7-multilib gcc-4.7-doc libstdc++6-4.7-dbg
  libstdc++6-4.7-doc

This confuses me. -_-

Comment: Those are the `build-essentials` dependencies. Those are a good idea for `setuptools` too. Note that `build-essentials` is *recommended*, so you can deselect that and stick with just `python-pip`.

Comment: I'm not that knowledgeable about linux and I'm just trying to be careful what to install because I have bad experiences regarding linux before like hang ups and messed up user interface

Comment: `build-essentials` will *not* muck up your linux installation.